# OCaml | regex operator

Tags: regex, ocaml

I have a regex that is not matching what I want it to.

```
"/.*\\.\\(css\\)\\|\\(js\\)\\|\\(png\\)"
```

This is currently matching:

```
/static/css/main.css
```

But it is not matching:

```
/static/js/prettify.js
```

Or:

```
/static/img/preview.png
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions for what I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Add `\\(` and `\\)` around `css` and `png`. Try this one `/.*\\.\\(\\(css\\)\\|\\(js\\)\\|\\(png\\)\\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify your regex without language-specific quoting:

```
.*\.(css)|(js)|(png)
         ↑
[       ]|[  ]|[   ]
```

You're matching `/static/css/main.css` because the first `|` applies on the pattern `.*\.(css)`. You should add another parenthesis around the extensions:

```
.*\.((css)|(js)|(png))
```

Now `.*\.` catches the first part (before the extension), and then you're looking for `css`, `js` or `png`.

In your language I think it'll be something like:

```
/.*\\.\\(\\(css\\)\\|\\(js\\)\\|\\(png\\)\\)
```

Comment: Great, I'll give it a go. Just curious, what is an example besides the one I gave that would match this regex? Like what is a string containing "js" that would match this regex?

Comment: @eatonphil your regex matches the string `png` and `js`.

Comment: @eatonphil It matches the above strings because the `|` appears between `.*\.css` and the rest, so if it doesn't match `.*\.css` it'll look for `js` or `png`.